# Can JMeter and LoadRunner runs the API test script developed in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, loadrunner, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing

My team is planning to do API Load Test using JMeter 5.0 and LoadRunner 12.63 on API calls developed on Kubernetes. I tried to research about someone already done this, but there's nothing much I can find, so few resources I can refer. Do I need to understand in depth of the Kubernetes architecture first?

If this is possible, how can I do this? And do LoadRunner really support to do API Load Testing? Appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Yes, this is possible for both tools

Answer (score 2):

Both tools are [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_end_and_back_end)-agnostic to wit from JMeter and/or Loadrunner perspective there is no difference where the system under test is deployed: on premise, in the cloud, on the [bare metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare-metal_server), in the [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), in the [container](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/blog/virtualization-via-containers/) (the latter one is exactly your case)

You don't need to have in-depth knowledge of Kubernetes deployment architecture for creating and running the test, you might need to have an insight when it comes to results analysis in order to be able to answer the question: where is the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and what needs to be done to resolve it.

Kubernetes deployments are supposed to be [auto-scaling](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes/) so it will be a good idea to conduct a [scalability test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) however it depends on your application deployment specifics. Just make sure that the containers [performance monitoring](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/) toolchain is in place, the most popular solution is [Prometheus](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/) however the other options could be possible starting from manually collecting OS/containers performance metrics, using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) or going for an end-to-end [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management)

Both JMeter and Loadrunner support API testing so I fail to see why would you need both tools, it would make more sense to stick to one you have more experience with or where it's faster/easier to implement your test scenario(s)

Comment: If I just want to practice doing this performance test on Kubernetes, first thing first I will need to install the Kubernetes in my PC, is it? Is Kubernetes only can run on Linux os? Can you confirm?

Comment: I have experience using JMeter and LoadRunner only once for both, that's why I would need both tools to implement the test scenario, just to compare for own enablement

Comment: Maybe [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) would be sufficient but if you want you can install [minicube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#minikube) - a single-node virtual Kubernetes cluster, it can be installed on Windows/Linux/MacOS. You can refer [How to Scale Selenium Tests in a Kubernetes Cluster](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/How-%20to-Scale-Selenium-Tests-in-a-Kubernetes-Cluster) article for example instructions

Comment: If I want to use JMeter PerfMon Plugin, how can I achieve to do the monitoring server part? Need to install the perfmon server agent in the Kubernetes server first?